# Syntax problem in calculated field

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to create a calculated field where I am trying to add Today date Column and 365 days. I think I applied wrong syntax. The text `[Today Date]+365` shown as it is in column entry.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post your entire formula in text, not image. It looks like you've only closed the OR statement, but haven't finished the IF statement.

Comment: You have the ([Today date] + 365) enclosed in double quotes, which i believe is making it a string

Answer (score 1):

Try the Formula

```
=Today+365
```

or

```
=[Today]+365
```

in order to get the current date + a year